# Can I upload similar videos in different languages on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I have a video, and I want to put different dubs or subtitles on different channels for different languages. In other words, I want to run different channels for different languages.

Google is [saying](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2801973?hl=en):

> Video Spam
> The following types of content are not allowed on YouTube. This isn't a complete list.
>
> - Content that promises viewers they'll watch something but instead directs them off site to view.
> - **Posting the same content repeatedly across one or more channels.**
> - Massively uploading content that you scraped from other creators.

What I'm trying to do is, the video itself covers the same content and is posted on different channels, but the subtitles and audio are different. I am not sure if this violates the guideline above. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned

> *"I am not sure if this violates the guideline above. Does anyone know?"*

Not quite sure if it does.

**As an alternative though**, why don't you just add your translations as captions and ease your mind?

[image]

Comment: I asked the question because some countries prefer to embed subtitles in videos, and while others like videos dubbed in their own language. Of course, I think this alternative is also good. Thanks.

Comment: **Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you**. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.